# var .htaccess not activating - cacheleak vulnerability

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, .htaccess

I recently ran a magereport.com scan on one of our magento sites and it reported a cacheleak vulnerability.

In my var folder, there is an .htaccess file but it is not activating and the vulnerability is still reported.

I am running the following:

```
Magento 1.8.1.0
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
PHP 5.3.3
FCGI
Apache 2.2.15
```

Contents of my var/.htaccess folder is:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

Can someone shed some light why I am still able to access folders in my var folder?

Comment: As far as i can see the `.htaccess` looks fine. are you actually able to see the contents of the `var` folder or is just magereport saying you can?

Answer (score 0):

while `.htaccess` is bad in many cases, you can add this in to your apache vhost config:

```
<LocationMatch ^/(app|downloader|pkginfo|includes|var)/>
    Deny from all
</LocationMatch>
```

just make sure you pass manual test, open `app` and `var` folder in your browser.

also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823915/htaccess-not-being-read

Comment: Thanks so much ... I did add that to my vhost config when this was first noticed.  The problem with that solution was no one could add items to their shopping cart.  I believe that was due to the sessions being stored on the filesystem in the var folder though.